# Passing sum from Sub Report to Master report Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report, subreport

I'm using CR 14.1. I have a Master report which is based from 4 sub reports. In one sub report, i have a sum formula but i want to display it in a different section on my Master report. I have tried using shared variables, but it does not work for me. The value that i get is always 0. The field that i'm suming is used only in the specific sub report

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you using that variable in main report before the sub report section or after the sub report section?

Comment: After the sub report section

Comment: Shared variable should work to pass the value from sub report to main report....can you post your formula?

Comment: sure.  this is my main report  Shared NumberVar x;  and this is from subreport Shared NumberVar x:= Sum ({Command.amount}); . Note that i want the value from the field to be passed from subreport to the main, not the other way

Answer (score 0):

Like Siva said you just have to use Share variables, just reference the same variable in both places

in the subreport

```
shared numebervar mynumber
mynumber := 100
```

in the main report

```
shared numebervar mynumber
mynumber
```

and the value is passed from the subreport to main report

Comment: I have discovered that the problem is not my code. I'm using similar code, and i get the value 0 in the first record and the value of the first record is assigned to the second record, when i click on the next page. That could mean two things. Either the two reports are not executed at the same time for some reason, or the value is not assigned at the beginning